# Nativescript not livesyncing

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I recently updated all my tns deps:

```
karlis@karlis-SATELLITE-L750 ~/Projects/my-instagram/test $ tns info
All NativeScript components versions information
┌──────────────────┬─────────────────┬────────────────┬─────────────┐
│ Component        │ Current version │ Latest version │ Information │
│ nativescript     │ 2.3.0           │ 2.3.0          │ Up to date  │
│ tns-core-modules │ 2.3.0           │ 2.3.0          │ Up to date  │
│ tns-android      │ 2.3.0           │ 2.3.0          │ Up to date  │
│ tns-ios          │ 2.3.0           │ 2.3.0          │ Up to date  │
```

When i change something in code and save, this shows up in console. However nothing changes in the app( closing and opening the app doesn't help too ):

```
4:42:18 PM - File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...

4:42:22 PM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.

Executing before-prepare hook from /home/karlis/Projects/my-instagram/test/hooks/before-prepare/nativescript-dev-typescript.js
Project successfully prepared (android)
Transferring project files...
Successfully transferred all files.
Applying changes...
Successfully synced application org.nativescript.test on device 3d828389.
```

Each time i run the command `tns livesync android --watch --device=3d828389` i get the full app reinstall and message showing: `The application with id "org.nativescript.test" is not installed on device with identifier 3d828389.` However the app IS installed on the phone.

Discuss.

Comment: Suggest you uninstall the app on the device and then do a tns run and then a tns livesync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my app/App_Resources/android/Manifest and gradle.

I changed them to original ones and it worked.